# IoT device with Ubuntu

Tags: intel-atom

I have an IoT device [(fitlet2)](https://fit-iot.com/web/products/fitlet2/fitlet2-specifications/) that is currently running a thin and secured ubuntu CLI version that I don't have access to root.
I would like to install a fresh install with GUI on the device and I am struggling to understand what version should I install?
The version I have is the E3930 with 8 gigs of RAM.

Comment: This device is using either an Atom or Celeron processor, so the standard version of Ubuntu (x64) will be the version you need to install 

Comment: What is a "thin...ubuntu...version?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)